# Hold back jquery event-handler for few miliseconds

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am creating a navigation menu. But it's still sorta buggy. I am stuck how to completely fine-tune it. Here is the problems you may have answers to solve them.

1. The menu (About Me | Portfolio | Blog | Contact Me) are easily triggered, I mean even a very quick passing-by hover can trigger them. How can I hold back the trigger (the mouseenter) for few milliseconds (say it 200ms) so that the futile unpurposed quick passing-by hover won't trigger the menu to work, I mean, the user really has to hover on the menu at least 200ms or if it's less than 200ms the menu won't be triggered? How?
2. The submenu (Portfolio One | Portfolio Two) sometimes, when their parent's hovered, one of them leaves already while the other one still stays, shudderedly. I guess it's because the failed easily-triggered menu portolfio hover too that affects its children; hence I need the hold-back of the menu so its children won't fade in and fade out recklessly and clutteredly.

Great thanks!

Here is the fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/Herza/ut5nLdpa/

Here is the code mix:

--------------HTML--------------------

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <p>About Me</p>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li><!--
     --><li id="portfolio" >
            <a>
                <p>Portfolio</p>
                <div></div>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li id="one-port">
                    <a href="#">Portfolio One</a>
                </li>
                <li id="two-port">
                    <a href="#" >Portfolio Two</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li><!--
     --><li>
            <a href="#" >
                <p>Blog</p>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li><!--
     --><li>
            <a href="#" >
                <p>Contact Me</p>
                <div></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    <ul>    
</nav>
```

---------------CSS-----------------

```
nav#menu .current {background-color: black; color: white;}
nav#menu > ul {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
nav#menu > ul > li {display: inline-block; list-style: none; position: relative;}
nav#menu > ul > li > a {text-decoration: none; display: block; padding: 0; height:  62px; width: 130px; text-align: center; font-family: "roboto-light"; line-height: 55px; color: black; font-size: 16px; cursor: pointer; overflow: hidden;}
nav#menu > ul > li > a > p {display: block; width: 100%; height: 62px; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: green;}
nav#menu > ul > li > a > div {display: block; width: 100%; height: 62px; margin: 0; padding: 0; background-color: black; background-image: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/3mJFQFK6QV2X2RZHfDGruGeelc7R4KhigZliqmQKZQqRMdm13ZOR2ZPtBf3VMyagahrzA4gT3ZcB4VU=w1342-h479); background-size: auto; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center center;}
nav#menu > ul > li > ul {position: absolute; left: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 200px; height: 0px; background-color: white; display: block; }
nav#menu > ul > li > ul > li {list-style: none}
nav#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a {display: block; padding: 15px 10px 15px 35px; background-color: white; color: black; text-decoration: none; font-family: "roboto-light";  font-size: 16px; background-color: blue;}
nav#menu > ul > li > ul > li { position: absolute; width: 100%; border: 0; left: 100px; display: none;}
nav#menu > ul > li > ul > li#one-port {top: 0px; z-index: 36;}
nav#menu > ul > li > ul > li#two-port {top: 49px; z-index: 35;}
nav#menu > ul > li > ul > li#one-port > a {border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
```

-------------------- Jquery --------------------------------

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("nav > ul > li").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children("a").children("p").animate({margin: "-62 0 0 0"},300);
    })
    $("nav > ul > li").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).children("a").children("p").animate({margin: "0 0 0 0"},300);
    })

    $("nav > ul > li#portfolio").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).children("ul").contents().clearQueue(); 
        $(this).children("ul").children("li#one-port").delay(0).queue(function(){
            $(this).animate({left: "0"},{queue: false, duration: 400})
            $(this).fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 400});
            $(this).dequeue();
        })
        $(this).children("ul").children("li#two-port").delay(250).queue(function(){
            $(this).animate({left: "0"},{queue: false, duration: 400})
            $(this).fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 400});
            $(this).dequeue();
        })
    })

    $("nav > ul > li#portfolio").mouseleave(function(){ 
        $(this).children("ul").contents().clearQueue();                                         
        $(this).children("ul").children("li#one-port").delay(0).queue(function(){
            $(this).animate({left: "100"},{queue: false, duration: 400})
            $(this).fadeOut({queue: false});
            $(this).dequeue();
        })
        $(this).children("ul").children("li#two-port").delay(250).queue(function(){
            $(this).animate({left: "100"},{queue: false, duration: 400})
            $(this).fadeOut({queue: false});
            $(this).dequeue();
        })      
    })
})
```

Comment: Try to add .stop() before all of your animations, because now if you hover a menu 5 times, the animation will play 5 times... I think that's why the strange bugs occur... You can also use .delay(200) before an animation to wait 2ms before start.

Comment: I have. It's apparently getting buggier when I added stop(), that's why I replaced stop() with clearQueue().

Comment: In fact I don't even use jQuery in cases like this, because it can be accomplished by simple CSS. Just use the :hover pseudo selector properly. For example, for showing the submenus of the hovered item, you can write a selector like     nav#menu > ul > li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

Comment: `.dequeue()` appear to be within `.queue()` function ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ut5nLdpa/1/ ?

Comment: Well, never mind the rest, my point is "How can I hold back the trigger (the mouseenter) for few milliseconds (say it 200ms) so that the futile unpurposed quick passing-by hover won't trigger the menu to work, I mean, the user really has to hover on the menu at least 200ms or if it's less than 200ms the menu won't be triggered?"

Comment: Thanks guys, I have it what I meant...

http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you already found a solution with the hoverintent plugin, which is fine, but allow me to share a solution that uses **no javascript at all**, just a few css transitions. This has the quite a few advantages:

- no need to load all those extra kB's for your javascript
- will degrade gracefully, even users without javascript will see the same menu
- css transitions are much better optimized, which will give a smoother animation
- you can stick to the [cheap properties](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/) like `translate` and `opacity`, which will not require a repaint. Again, much better performance. This can be done in jQuery as well, but not without adding yet another plugin that allows you to animate the `transform` properties.

Without further ado, [this is what I came up with](https://jsfiddle.net/ut5nLdpa/2/). I know it is not an exact replica, you will have to fiddle with the numbers a bit, but consider it a proof of concept. the actual code is surprisingly simple:

**HTML:**

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Digital Illustration</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
    </ul>   
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
/* general */
nav a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 18px;
}
nav ul {
    list-style: none;
}

/* main menu */
nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
}
nav > ul > li > a {
    background: green;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
nav > ul > li > a:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: black;
    transform: translate(0, 100%);
    transition: transform .4s .2s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > a:after {
    transform: translate(0,0);
}

/* sub menu */
nav > ul > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
}
nav > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: blue;
    transform: translate(100%, 0);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: transform .4s .3s, opacity .4s .3s;
}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul > li > a {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}

/* repeat this for each sub item you add, increasing the child 
   number (2) and adding .2s to the delay. Can be easily automated 
   with a css preprocessor like sass or less
*/
nav > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a {
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
```

As I said, the code is quite straight forward, but feel free to ask if you want me to explain anything.

Comment: Wow! awesome. You really meant to help, your answer is pretty elaborative. I can read CSS3, relax, no need to explain, I just didn't find out (I tried actually) how to create it with CSS3 animation. Thanks a lot, dude!